# Where does Firefox get the icons for the website tiles on the home page

Tags: firefox

In firefox the home page has a grid of tiles for website links.

These tiles have icons but they are not the site favicons.

Eg. for

https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/scores-fixtures
Firefox got this ;
[image]

But

https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/scores-fixtures gets this ;[image]

Anyone know how/where Firefox gets the icon ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose firefox gets it from the HTML's metadata. Taking a look at the source code, it contains entries like these:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://m.files.bbci.co.uk/modules/bbc-morph-sport-page/3.3.2/images/bbc-sport-logo.png"/>
```

which links to this image:

https://m.files.bbci.co.uk/modules/bbc-morph-sport-page/3.3.2/images/bbc-sport-logo.png

The `og:image` name comes from the [Open Graph protocol](https://ogp.me/).